# How do you select an unique id in an DB2 table that was generated using DB2 generate unique() function?

Tags: sql, db2, cobol

I would like to select the information from a DB2 table, using that unique id that was generated using DB2 generate unique() function as key in a simple select query.

Using the field directly, gives an SQL code of -333, using HEX(unique id) in select gives SQL code of +100.

How can i get the information from the table?

Comment: This is a programming website.  __show your code ___.   The `Generate_Unique` returns `char(13) for bit data`.   When querying, the datatype of the host-variable must be compatible.

Comment: Your cobol preprocessor should understand `01 ... SQL TYPE IS BINARY(13)` and generate the appropriate structure.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the data type of your parameter.
If you know its hex representation, then:

```
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE SESSION.GEN_UNIQUE (U) AS (VALUES GENERATE_UNIQUE()) 
WITH DATA WITH REPLACE ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS NOT LOGGED;

SELECT HEX(U) AS HEX_VAL 
FROM SESSION.GEN_UNIQUE
WHERE U = HEXTORAW ('20210531172108210028000000');

|HEX_VAL                   |
|--------------------------|
|20210531172108210028000000|
```

If you have it as `CHAR(13) FOR BIT DATA`, then it can be used as usual:

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
BEGIN
  DECLARE L_VAR CHAR(13) FOR BIT DATA;
  DECLARE L_DUMMY INT;
  
  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
  BEGIN 
    RESIGNAL SQLSTATE '70001' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Oops!'; 
  END;
  
  SET L_VAR = HEXTORAW('20210531172108210028000000');
  SELECT 1 INTO L_DUMMY
  FROM SESSION.GEN_UNIQUE
  WHERE U = L_VAR;
END
@
```